# $L_2$ space in harmonic analysis

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Let ${v_n}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a closed orthonormal system in $L^2[0,1]$. We want to prove that for every $a\in[0,1]$, we have

$$a=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\int_0^a \overline{v_n(x)}dx\right|^2$$

where $\overline{v_n(x)}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $v_n(x)$.

now the solution was like this , but I have no idea what is that and how they solved it using this function and someone explain please
\begin{equation*}
|1_{[0,a]}|2 = {\sum |\langle 1_{[0,a]}, \phi_n\rangle|^2}
\end{equation*}

Comment: When you say you have no idea, do you mean you don't even know the definition of the symbols?

Comment: What's the 1 function ? , like constant 1 in [0,a]?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). It is better you point out exactly what you do not know in the post.